# K6 HTML report generation via command line

Tags: performance-testing, k6

We had ran into use case where we need to generate a HTML report via command line which contains only end metrics of the test? From the knowledge articles could able to get only handle summary callback function but that doesn’t fits our need. Is there anyway that we could do it via command line? Is ther a a way to write metrics that are returned to stdout to a seperate HTML line via command line?

Comment: Why doesn't `handleSummary` work? From where would your report (generator) get its data from?

Comment: Handle summary actually works well, but we are providing k6 as service to others by developing a custom tool around it, we need to generate HTML report via command line after the test execution completes.

Comment: I hope you do the AGPL-3 license justice and release the source code of your tools :)